# Polygon is not fully filled with color in threejs

Tags: javascript, d3.js, three.js

I am trying to draw a lot of complex polygons that represent a part of a country (image bellow).
Each polygon has unique colour.

The borders of the polygons are drawn correctly (they represent the borders of the municipalities). However, as you can see from the image bellow, the polygons are not filled correctly.

[image]

Here is the code that I am currently using for drawing the borders:

```
// Converts a GeoJSON MultiLineString in spherical coordinates to a THREE.LineSegments.
  function wireframe(multilinestring, material) {
    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry;
    multilinestring.coordinates.forEach(function (line) {

      d3.pairs(line.map(vertex), function (a, b) {
          geometry.vertices.push(a, b);
      });
    });
    return new THREE.LineSegments(geometry, material);
  }
```

and here is the code that I am using for drawing the filled polygons :

```
  function fillShape(multilinestring) {
      var points = [];

      multilinestring.coordinates.forEach(function (line) {
          d3.pairs(line.map(vertex), function (a, b) {
              points.push(a, b)
          });
      });

      var geometry = new THREE.ConvexGeometry(points);
      var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: (0xffffff * Math.random() )});

      return new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  }
```

The multilinestring variable contains the points that represent the borders.
The same values are used for drawing the borders and the filled polygons.
Why are the polygons not filled correctly, and is there a way to fill them correctly ?

**EDIT:**

Based on the example provided by prisoner849 in the comments, I updated the code to the following:

```
multilinestring.coordinates.forEach(function (line) {
d3.pairs(line.map(vertex), function (a, b) {
vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(a.x, a.y, a.z),new THREE.Vector3(b.x, b.y,b.z));
});
});


var shape =new THREE.Shape(vertices)
var geometry = new THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry(shape);
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:(0xffffff * Math.random() ), side: THREE.DoubleSide}));
```

Now the polygons are filled correctly, but they are misplaced (drawn on a different position than before). I am using the same verticies coordinates that I used in the previous example, so I am not sure what changed the position of the polygons.

Comment: You have to triangulate your polygons. Using of `THREE.ConvexGeometry()` is not correct way for it. It's better to use `THREE.Shape()` and `THREE.ShapeGeometry()`/`THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry()`. Take a look at this [example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=shapes#webgl_geometry_shapes).

Comment: In particular, see [this three.js example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes2.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I updated the post with the changes I made and the new issue that arised from them.

Comment: @Dvorog could you create a live code example?

Comment: I will try to create one later. I think that the problem is caused by the fact that Shape ignores the Z coordinate.  (I am trying to place the polygons on a sphere).